# jquery ui vertical slider with custom handle. Handle won't move.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to combine two examples to make a vertical slider with a custom handle that displays its value.

https://jqueryui.com/slider/#custom-handle

https://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical

I was able to get the slider to move and update the value on the naked vertical slider example by selecting the slider with a css class but this won't work for me since I will have numerous sliders on the page.

Any advice on how I can get this slider to work right?

Codepen example here:

https://codepen.io/cschroeder/pen/EXXqqv

js:

```
$( function() {
   var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );
    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 9,
      value:0,
      create: function() {
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        //$(".ui-slider-handle").text(ui.value);
        handle.text( ui.value );                
      }
    });

  } );
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css">

<div id="slider-vertical" style="height:200px;">
<div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#custom-handle {
    width: 3em;
    height: 1.6em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.8em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line "top: 50%" from your CSS markup.  In vertical orientation, the slider code is changing the "bottom" parameter but it has no effect while the "top" parameter is set.